# Passing global constant as 'this' argument discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, global-variables, constants

In my program I have a global `const std::map` variable and a function which attempts to read its contents. The compiler (G++ 5.2.0 C++0x) then gives me an error that `passing ‘const std::map<const char*, const char>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`. I cannot specify the cv-qualifier to the function since it is not a member function. What do I do?

The code is the following:

```
const map <const char*, const char> opcodes = 
{
    {"ABCDE", 123},
};

bool _cmdmatch (const char* cmd, const char* cmdlist[], char count)
{
    ...
        if (opcodes[cmd] == opcodes[cmdlist[i]]) return true;
        //if (opcodes.at(cmd) == opcodes.at(cmdlist[i])) return true; //The solution
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does the map get passed by reference or by value?

Comment: You really should supply, at least, the code that causes the error.

Comment: The code is the following: .....where is the code??

Comment: What is so hard about presenting a MCVE? Why must we ask for one on _every_ dang question? Sigh.

Comment: Sorry, my connection went down in the middle of editing. Here's the snippet of code ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using `operator[]` to read from the map, which can't be used on a `const` map. You should use `at()` to take an element with a specific key, or `find()` to search for an element. Both have `const` versions and can be used on a `const` map.